# How to switch environment in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can one switch environment in Rails 3?

Comment: Care to elaborate? What exactly do you mean by 'switch environment'?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the environment flag:

`rails s --environment=production`

Or set the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to save keystrokes:

```
rails s -e production
```